# ZK progressmeter is not working with for loop without events

Tags: java, process, zk

I am using ZK framework. I just want to insert lots of rows into my MySQL database. While inserting data it takes few seconds. During that time I just want to show a progress meter, which tells user about the number of rows inserted into the database.

I tried like this:

```
rowCount = qModel.executeInsert();      
for(long j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++)
{
    sum = sum + 100 / rowCount;
    if (j == rowCount)
    {               
        sum = 100;
    }   
    progressMeter.setValue(sum);            
    countLabel.setValue((rowCount - 1) + " Rows inserted");
    BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, countLabel, "_value");
}
```

Here `rowCount` is the total number of rows inserted into the database. I know after the inserting process the progress meter is getting updated.
But i want my progress meter updated with no busy tag.

If anyone knows the solution, help me out. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help me out through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually simple,

As long your in the same Execution, no updates will happen to your GUI.
Your only solution is working with multiple call's, achieved by a Timer or enable server push.

It all seems complicated but there is also good news.
Robert Wenzel has written a small talk about simplifying long operations and it include the whole basic for simplifying this.

Please take a look at this :

https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2015/January/Simplify_Long_Operation_Handlings